# Sending messages to TApplication

Tags: delphi, winapi

I have an application that can send a message to another application. Under pre-Win8 systems, that works fine. You give it the class or title, it uses enumwindows and finds the target window. With Win8, you can only enumerate top level windows, which means the TApplication class. The sending side is happy with that, but the receiver isn't.

To catch the message I'm using this code within my target form ...

```
function Tmain.AppMsgHookFunc(var wmsg : TMessage) : Boolean;
begin
  Result := False; 
  if wmsg.Msg = WM_COPYDATA then begin
    // Post the caught message back to this form.
    postmessage (handle,wmsg.Msg,wmsg.WParam,wmsg.LParam);
  end;
end;
```

... and then activate this with application.hookmainwindow etc.

This never fires. I see that if I use sendmessage to send myself the message then it does fire, but if I use postmessage that doesn't work, even on XP. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`WM_COPYDATA` is a sent message. The system marshals data cross-process. In order to do so, the system must know that the message has been processed in order to be able to tidy up the resources used to make the cross-process marshalling happen. And the way that the system knows that the message has been processed is by forcing you to send it synchronously. That means you must use `SendMessage` rather than `PostMessage`.

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms649011.aspx) also contains this information, although you do need to know how to interpret it.

> An application sends the WM_COPYDATA message to pass data to another application.

Note the use of the word "sends". That is code for the message being synchronous.

Raymond Chen discusses this issue here: [Why can't I PostMessage the WM_COPYDATA message, but I can SendMessageTimeout it with a tiny timeout?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/09/16/10208976.aspx)

> The important difference from the standpoint of messages like
>   WM_COPY­DATA is that with sent messages, the window manager knows when
>   message processing is complete: When the window procedure returns. At
>   that time, it can free the temporary buffers used to marshal the
>   message from the sender to the recipient. If the message were posted,
>   the window manager would never be sure.
>
> Suppose the message is placed in a MSG structure as the result of a
>   call to GetMessage. Now the window manager knows that the receiving
>   thread has the potential for taking action on the message and the
>   buffers need to be valid. But how would it know when the buffers can
>   be freed? "Well you can wait until the exact same parameters get
>   passed in a MSG structure to the Dispatch­Message function." But what
>   if the message loop discards the message? Or what if it decides to
>   dispatch it twice? Or what if it decides to smuggle it inside another
>   message?
>
> Posted messages have no guarantee of delivery nor do they provide any
>   information as to when the message has been definitely processed, or
>   even if it has been processed at all. If the window manager let you
>   post a WM_COPY­DATA message, it would have to use its psychic powers
>   to know when the memory can be freed.

Comment: That's fantastically helpful, thanks very much for your detailed answer!